# EXCEL opens in Windows 7, but gives error in Windows Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell

I have a script that generates an EXCEL spreadsheet. I can easily open this in my Windows 7 workstation, but when I try to open this in Windows Server 2012 I get the error

[image]

And when I click "OK" I get

[image]

And here is the jist of the code

```
$SQL1 = "..."

$SQL2 = "..."

$SQL3 = "..." 

$SQL4 = "..." 



# Create Excel file to save the data

if (!(Test-Path -path "$DirectoryToSave")) #create it if not existing 
  { 
  New-Item "$DirectoryToSave" -type directory | out-null 
  } 

$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $True
$wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Add()
$currentWorksheet=1

$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
$ws.name = "GUP Download Activity"


$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN;UID=$username;PWD=$password", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL1)

if ($qt.Refresh()){
    $ws.Activate()
    $ws.Select()
    ...
}

$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(2)
$ws.name = "Totals"


$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN;UID=$username;PWD=$password", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL2)

if ($qt.Refresh()){
    $ws.Activate()
    $ws.Select()
    ...
 }


$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(3)
$ws.name = "GUP Downloads per Computer"


$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN;UID=$username;PWD=$password", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL3)

if ($qt.Refresh()){
    $ws.Activate()
    $ws.Select()
    ...
 }


$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(4)
$ws.name = "GUP Monthly Trends"


$qt = $ws.QueryTables.Add("ODBC;DSN=$DSN2;UID=$username;PWD=$password", $ws.Range("A1"), $SQL4)

if ($qt.Refresh()){
    $ws.Activate()
    $ws.Select()
    ...
 }


$filename = "D:\Script\Daily_GUP_Report1.xlsx"
if (test-path $filename ) { rm $filename } 
$wb.SaveAs($filename,  $xlOpenXMLWorkbook) #save as an XML Workbook (xslx) 
$wb.Saved = $True #flag it as being saved 
$wb.Close() #close the document 
$Excel.Quit() #and the instance of Excel 
$wb = $Null #set all variables that point to Excel objects to null 
$ws = $Null #makes sure Excel deflates 
$Excel=$Null #let the air out
```

Comment: Is Excel the same version on your desktop vs the server?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg The EXCEL on desktop is 2010, and the one on server is 2007

Comment: Take a look [here](http://lewisvhall.com/?p=248) - if any of these work, post back the answer so people can find when they view your question.

Comment: I would suggest breaking the script down. Set it up so it creates an empty spreadsheet and test this. Assuming this works, add the other elements back a few at a time and test each time. You should be able to work out where the problem cells are.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg your link worked. I went to 1: start->run and type ‘DCOMCNFG’

2: Open ‘DCOM Config’ and locate ‘Microsoft Excel Application’

3: Set its identity to ‘The Launching User’.

Comment: Great, glad you got it working.  It would be helpful if you posted that as an answer and marked it as such, then people searching for the same issue and finding your post will find the answer easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was one of the suggestions [here](http://lewisvhall.com/?p=248)

1: start->run and type ‘DCOMCNFG’
2: Open ‘DCOM Config’ and locate
    ‘Microsoft Excel Application’
3: Set its identity to ‘The Launching
    User